# Can't get my appId from my intrumentationKey : Appinsight

Tags: .net, azure, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to get my AddId from my intrumentation key through this method :

```
ApplicationInsightsApplicationIdProvider toto = new ApplicationInsightsApplicationIdProvider();
            bool test = toto.TryGetApplicationId(_configuration["ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey"], out string applicationId);
```

However the result that i get is always false, it's as if my app insight doesn't exist.

Someone know why ?

Comment: are you sure instrumentation key from your configuration is valid?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check the existance of an App insight with a correspondent instrumentation key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53227483/check-the-existance-of-an-app-insight-with-a-correspondent-instrumentation-key)

Comment: this appears to be a dup of your other question?

Comment: if you run fiddler or something, do you see an outbound request that tries to look it up?  you should see: `https://dc.services.visualstudio.com/api/profiles/{your ikey}/appId` as a rquest when you call the method.  if you don't, are you doing something else that's causing the request to be blocked?

Comment: @JohnGardner, what he means is that he  wanna check if app insights instance exists or not by using instrumentation key, I have confirmed with him in his last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53227483/check-the-existance-of-an-app-insight-with-a-correspondent-instrumentation-key).

Comment: @IvanYang so do you have the solution on how to check if the app insights exists or not ?

Comment: I have the same issue with you, and still work on it. And I think @JohnGardner may have some insights on this. If any updates, I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this manually :

```
   private bool TryGetApplicationId(string intrumentationKey, out string appId)
            {
                RestClient restClient = new RestClient("https://dc.services.visualstudio.com");
                RestRequest request = new RestRequest(string.Format("api/profiles/{0}/appId", intrumentationKey), Method.GET);
                RestResponse response = (RestResponse) restClient.Execute(request);
                appId = response.Content;
                return response.IsSuccessful;
            }
```